# Bluemix Push Notification Registration ID list

Tags: push-notification, ibm-cloud

I can now get the Registration ID from the mobile and the push notification is working properly. I can access the list with the help of REST APIs but what I want to know is how to access the Registration ID list in the Bluemix itself where I'm not creating any tag.

Comment: Is this a follow-up to one of your previous questions? Please provide more context about what you are trying to do, so that we can find an answer for you.

Comment: No it not a follow up. I know that I can retrieve that the Reg Id list through API but I want to know how to get it in bluemix itself like as in UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated above, with the Bluemix Push Notification Service you can use REST APIs in order to gather the deviceIds from registered devices. We also provide a document that allows you to test these APIs directly in the browser:

https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfpushrestapidocs/#!/devices/get_apps_applicationId_devices

Currently we do not provide a list of registered deviceIDs via the Bluemix dashboard, but you can use the Monitoring tab in the Push Notification dashboard to gather some statistics on the number of registered devices.

Comment: what happened to the Monitoring tab?